# Android data binding does not observe kotlin's liveData builder

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-livedata

Android data binding does not observe kotlin's liveData builder

the following code will create a LiveData and it's supposed to be observed by data binding in `XML` but it doesn't work

```
val text =
        liveData(Dispatchers.Default) {
            emit("Hello")
}
```

on the other hand if it's gets observed in `Kotlin` it works fine

```
  vm.text.observe(lifeCycleOwner,{
            binding.texti.text = it
        })
```

the xml:

```xml
 <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/texti"
                android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
           />
```

and if i change the definition of live data to:

```
val text = MutableLiveData("Hello")
```

data binding automatically observes and sets the text

Am i doing it wrong or it's a bug?

Answer (score 6):

Did you set lifecycle owner of the binding? The binding initialization should look like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<MyActivityBinding>(this, R.layout.my_activity)
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel.get()
    ...
}
```

Fore more details, see: [Use LiveData to notify the UI about data changes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata)

Comment: As i said it works the other way, so it means these settings are already done. Thank you for your kind answer

Comment: @sajad Could you add the whole initialization code of your activity, view model and layout xml to the question? The binding should work, I even created a minimal sample app, and it works fine.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I've spent a day forgetting this and your answer totally fixed my problem, a simple line of code can ruin your night's sleep! LOL